# How to remove white screen in ionic application

Tags: authentication, ionic-framework, ionic4, splash-screen

I have created an ionic application and when I load my application after splash screen and before login page a white flicker comes  for about 3-4 seconds. But I want to remove it in my application .So please suggest how to do it.

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

Comment: make your build with prod attribute 
`ionic cordova build android --prod ` this will optimize your build and decrease your white screen time.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to add below preference in config.xml file

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
```

then use this "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" and check this link to add this plugin
[splash screen cordova plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/splash-screen)

and in app.component.ts in intializeApp folder or in custructor put this code

```
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
         this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
```

and make sure when you make production build then use ionic cordova build android --prod.
I hope this will help you.